# Can't select one image only when using multiple image selection mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have an app where the user should be able to select multiple images from his gallery and send them
everything is working fine except if the user decides he wants to send only one image the image is not retrieved in the onActivtyResult method here is my code
launching the intent to choose image

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMG);
//PICK_IMG=1
```

my on activity result

```
@Override
    public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("step 1");
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMG) {
            System.out.println("step 2");
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                System.out.println("step 3");
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    System.out.println("step 4");
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                    int CurrentImageSelect = 0;

                    while (CurrentImageSelect < count) {
                        Uri imageuri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(CurrentImageSelect).getUri();
                        ImageList.add(imageuri);
                        CurrentImageSelect = CurrentImageSelect + 1;
                    }
                  
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

when selecting multiple images its working perfectly but when selecting only one image it reaches step3 then data.getClipData() returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a single image it is not returned in `data.getClipData()` instead android set it into `data` part `data.getData()`, which is a `Uri`. You can do it like below.

```
@Override
    public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("step 1");
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMG) {
            System.out.println("step 2");
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                System.out.println("step 3");
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    System.out.println("step 4");
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                    int CurrentImageSelect = 0;

                    while (CurrentImageSelect < count) {
                        Uri imageuri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(CurrentImageSelect).getUri();
                        ImageList.add(imageuri);
                        CurrentImageSelect = CurrentImageSelect + 1;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    if (uri != null) {
                        //uri of the single image
                    }
                }
            }

            }

        }
```